Disable Publish/Subscribe Behavior in spring-session Library
I am using the spring-session library in my web application, and I noticed that the internal logic triggers a Publish/Subscribe mechanism. For my specific use case, I would like to prevent this behavior.
To achieve this, I plan to modify the library by commenting out certain parts of the code responsible for Publish/Subscribe, then package it as a custom JAR and use it in my web application.
Additionally, I have set the notify-keyspace-events option in Redis to an empty value (""), but the Publish/Subscribe behavior persists.
Before proceeding, I have a few questions:

Is there an official way to disable the Publish/Subscribe behavior without modifying the source code?
If not, would modifying the code in the library be an acceptable approach, or could this lead to potential issues with future updates?
Are there any alternative ways to configure or disable this behavior without changing the library's source code?

Any guidance on how to address this would be greatly appreciated.
[To disable Publish behavior]
spring-session/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis
/RedisIndexedSessionRepository.java
@Override
    public void save(RedisSession session) {
        session.save();
/* commenting out
        if (session.isNew) {
            String sessionCreatedKey = getSessionCreatedChannel(session.getId());
            this.sessionRedisOperations.convertAndSend(sessionCreatedKey, session.delta);
            session.isNew = false;
        }
*/
    }

[To disable Subscribe behavior]
spring-session/spring-session-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http
/RedisIndexedHttpSessionConfiguration.java
@Bean
    public RedisMessageListenerContainer springSessionRedisMessageListenerContainer(
            RedisIndexedSessionRepository sessionRepository) {
        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(getRedisConnectionFactory());
        if (this.redisTaskExecutor != null) {
            container.setTaskExecutor(this.redisTaskExecutor);
        }
        if (this.redisSubscriptionExecutor != null) {
            container.setSubscriptionExecutor(this.redisSubscriptionExecutor);
        }
/* commenting out

        container.addMessageListener(sessionRepository,
                Arrays.asList(new ChannelTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionDeletedChannel()),
                        new ChannelTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionExpiredChannel())));
        container.addMessageListener(sessionRepository,
                Collections.singletonList(new PatternTopic(sessionRepository.getSessionCreatedChannelPrefix() + "*")));
*/
        return container;
    }

This is what I might do
